# How to map business actions to rest urls

Tags: rest

How do I map business actions correctly to rest urls?

For example:

- To get an order, I use `GET` on `/customers/{id}/orders/{id}`
- To create a new order, I use `POST` on `/customers/{id}/orders

But how to map revoking of an order. Revoking triggers an individual business process and do not only change some fields (like the status)?

`GET` or `PUT` to `/customers/{id}/orders/{id}/revoke` without any content??

Comment: you can use simply `DELETE /customers/{id}/orders/{id}` or `PUT /customers/{id}/orders/{id}` to update status

Comment: Is your business process [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)? If it is, use `PUT`. If it isn't, use `POST`. Do not use `DELETE` if the resource still exists (presumably in a "revoked" state) after the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `POST` to `/customers/{id}/orders/{id}/revoke`.

According to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5), POST is designed to cover a range of functions, not just creating a resource. Moreover GET and PUT are expected to be idempotent, whereas POST does not need to be.

For this kind of business operation you then need to determine the appropriate function, and response, to implement on the server against the POST. Broadly speaking your options are:

- For asynchronous operation, create a temporary resource describing the status of the action and return a 201 (Created) or 202 response (Accepted) pointing to that action-status resource.
- For synchronous operation, just do whatever is needed to revoke the order and then return a 204 (No Content) or 205 response (Reset Content).

Refer to the [HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to see which response code is more appropriate for your scenario.

(This is all assuming, of course, that you can't simply DELETE the order without breaking your business process.)